# angularjs how to increment init variable value in ng-repeat without onclick?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to increment init variable value in ng-repeat

```
   <div ng-if="feedData.carouselMode == true" ng-init='start=0'  ng-repeat="a in carousel_data">

            <div  class="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel"   owl-carousel >
            <div class="item"  ng-repeat="(key, item) in a.carouselFeeds" ng-init="start=start+1">
                {{start}}
                <div ng-click="go('{{key}}', item.feedUrls.length, 'rtl')" ng-swipe-left="go('{{key}}', item.feedUrls.length, 'rtl')">
            <img class="lazyOwl"  ng-src="{{item.img}}"  />  
            <span class="innersquare" image-ja="{{item.img}}"> 
                <p ng-style="folderStyle">{{item.name  }}&nbsp;</p> </span>
                 </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ng-init start=0 after increment start=start+1 in ng-repeat but no count only show 1.

Comment: Why don't you use `$index`?

Comment: `$index` will also starts from 0. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: What do you want from this combination ?

Comment: @angu is it fine for you now ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because each `ng-repeat` has its own scope and each `ng-init` will just increase its own scoped variable. You can try access the parent scope with `$parent`.

In case you are looking for a continuous numeration try this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="a in ['a','b','c']" ng-init="current = $parent.start; $parent.start=$parent.start+3;">
        <div ng-repeat="x in ['alpha','beta','gamma']">
            {{current + $index}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the `+3` should be `+[LENGTH OF INNER ARRAY]`.

http://jsfiddle.net/rvgvs2jt/2/

For your specific code it would look like this

```
<div ng-if="feedData.carouselMode == true" ng-init='current=$parent.start; $parent.start=$parent.start+a.carouselFeeds.length' ng-repeat="a in carousel_data">
    <div class="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel" owl-carousel>
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="(key, item) in a.carouselFeeds">
            {{current + $index}}
            <div ng-click="go('{{key}}', item.feedUrls.length, 'rtl')" ng-swipe-left="go('{{key}}', item.feedUrls.length, 'rtl')">
                <img class="lazyOwl" ng-src="{{item.img}}" />
                <span class="innersquare" image-ja="{{item.img}}"> 
                <p ng-style="folderStyle">{{item.name  }}&nbsp;</p> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was creating fiddle and you beat be by 40 sec :-P

Comment: It's fine we solved it together +1 for your effort. :-P

Comment: @Rouby you need to add +1 to start it from 1 not 0.

Comment: please help me. i am using this fiddle and  i need this correct solution please check it      https://jsfiddle.net/7sqe9kqb/1/

Comment: thanks  @Rouby . what is $parent.start? can you explain to me

Comment: Just another scope variable, it represents the accumulated length of all previous inner arrays. It gets copied to `current` so that we can circumvent angulars binding and display the value of that variable at that time (in the inner ng-repeat) instead of the most recent value (which would be the final length of all inner arrays)

Answer (score 6):

I guess you achieve this by simple {{$parent.$index}}

**Update**

As per comments

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="a in one">
        <div ng-repeat="x in two">
            {{($parent.$index*two.length)+($index+1)}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:-

```
$scope.one= ['alpha','beta','gamma'] ;
$scope.two=['alpha','beta','gamma'];
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjswhy18/)

Comment: i need count nested ng repeat value only please help me

Comment: can you explain with simple example

Comment: ng-repeat="x in ['alpha','beta','gamma']" length  3  after loop load show same length i need 4 5 6 count . are you ok what i mean?

Comment: Look you have ng-repeat="x in [a,b,c]" and inside it you have ng-repeat=" y in  ['alpha','beta','gamma']" . And you want to print what for x is a and y is alpha ,x is a and y is beta and x is a y is gamma .Again x is b and So on ....??

Comment: jsfiddle.net/3Lt21u6 is write fiddle  but i want 123456789 index please can you help me?

Comment: Great Happy coding dear :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works if the inner array length is always the same.

Comment: please help me. i am using this fiddle and i need this correct solution please check it  jsfiddle.net/7sqe9kqb/1

Comment: @angu sorry  didn't considered about it.In that case you need to keep track the last known parent start location .

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e53m9zpw/

Answer (score 3):

You can be accessed with [$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), check this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/gHFhk/),

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">
    <label>Input {{$index+1}}:</label>
    <input ng-model="item.value" type="text"/>
  </div>
  {{list}}
</div>
```

and

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.list = [ { value: 'value 1' }, { value: 'value 2' }, { value: 'value 3' } ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
AngularJS is giving $index variable. We can use it.     
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ $index + 1 }}</li>
</ul>
```