# AngularJS increment id value of items in nested repeater

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following code in which there are questions and choices and I need the choices to have incremented id values.

However, I need the incrementation to restart each time there is a new question. Most of the examples I've found so far increment for all (e.g. using $index). But I've looked at several articles here on SO such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297301/angularjs-how-to-increment-init-variable-value-in-ng-repeat-without-onclick) and not getting the results that I need:

What I need is this:

```
 Question 1
     Choice10 (the first numerical value is the Id of the question,
     Choice11  the second numerical value should be the incremented id)
     Choice12
 Question 2
     Choice20
     Choice21
     Choice22
     Choice23
```

The html code looks like this:

```
<table summary="" style="border: none; width: 100%; background: none;" id="rptQuestions">
      <tbody>
        <tr style="width: 100%;" ng-repeat-start="q in questions track by $index"> 
             ...Question details here...        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Bold_10" colspan="4">
            <table summary="" style="border: none; background: none">
                <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat-start="c in choices" ng-if="c.QuestionId==q.QuestionId">
                        <td style="width: 2em;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="DeleteChoice(c)">X</a></td>
                        <td>
                             <input type="text" id="inLetter{{c.QuestionId}}{{ value?? }}" ng-model="c.Letter" style="width: 2em;" /></td>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                             <input type="text" id="inChoice{{c.QuestionId}}{{ value?? }}" ng-model="c.Choice" style="width: 60em;" />                                                                                  <input type="hidden" id="inChoiceId{{c.QuestionId}}{{ value?? }}" ng-value="{{c.Id}}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="c.QuestionId==null"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table summary="" style="border: none; width: 100%; background: none;" id="rptQuestions">
      <tbody>
        <tr style="width: 100%;" ng-repeat-start="q in questions"> 
             ...Question details here...        
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end="">
            <td class="Bold_10" colspan="4">
            <table summary="" style="border: none; background: none">
                <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat-start="c in choices" ng-if="c.QuestionId==q.QuestionId">
                        <td style="width: 2em;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="DeleteChoice(c)">X</a></td>
                        <td>
                             <input type="text" id="inLetter{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" ng-model="c.Letter" style="width: 2em;" /></td>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                             <input type="text" id="inChoice{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" ng-model="c.Choice" style="width: 60em;" />                                                                                  <input type="hidden" id="inChoiceId{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" ng-value="{{c.Id}}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="c.QuestionId==null"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Each ng-repeat has its own index and you can access the index from the nested loop. However be aware that with your implementation the id inChoice111 might be misleading.

Question 1.11 == Question 11.1

Comment: When I did the $index on the choices I did not get 0,1,2 for question 1, 0,1,2 for question 2. It started at 0 on question 1 and gave me 3,4, 5 for question 2. Could it be because I'm using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end?

Comment: Not sure,  that sounds weird. Have you tried to remove the ng-repeat-start?

Comment: Also you are not closing the first ng-repeat-start, maybe better getting rid of them.

Comment: I'd also put a hyphen between the index numbers, otherwise "parent 1, child 11," will be the same as "parent 11, child 1."

Comment: @xbirkettx It is being closed, I forgot to put that part in the markup. Also, I can't remove the ng-repeat-start because the questions are an array as well as the choices and I need all the elements inside to be repeated. I finally decided this wasn't the way to resolve my issue so I added a hidden field with a class that has the value of the id of each choice and I'm just doing a for loop over these values in javascript, this  helped eliminate the issue with duplicate id's being a possibility, thanks for catching that.