# data-ng-repeat for i from 0 to array length

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array called "design", with dynamic length. I want to show all the elements of this array in more  cells of a table. I write this code:

```html
<tr style="cursor:pointer" data-ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5]">             
      <td ng-click="changePath(dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ design[$index] }}</td>  
</tr>
```

but I want to repeat data for `i in [0, . . . , design.length]`, not to 5. Length of design is not 5, but it change dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do (if no duplicates in design):

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="obj in design">             
      <td ng-click="changePath(dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ obj }}</td>  
</tr>
```

Or (if duplicates in design):

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="obj in design track by $index">             
      <td ng-click="changePath(dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ obj }}</td>  
</tr>
```

Comment: This doesn't works in this case, I had already tried. I posted the solution

Comment: No no! I have a vector! I used your solution in other cases. I have a vector of n elements, it's a different case

Comment: What are the elements? Strings and integers?

Comment: Updated my answer to include both cases

Comment: @AlfonsoSilvestri no reason this shouldn't work. Your comment about `vector` makes no sense

Answer (score -3):

Solved in this way:

```html
<tr style="cursor:pointer" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(design.length) track by $index">             
     <td ng-click="changePath(dispensercategory.dispenser.iddispenser)"> {{ design[$index] }}</td>  
</tr>
```

And in my js file:

```html
 $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
}
```

Comment: This is code bloat to simply iterate the design array in the view

Comment: This is the only solution for my application. This works. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29297502/5221435

Comment: Still makes no sense vs iterating the design array itself

Comment: this answer shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how arrays and `ng-repeat` function.